# How to find out when a screen shot was taken?

Tags: display, screenshot

I have a screen shot of a desktop without the date of it that my friend sent me. When I right click on it and go to properties it says that it was taken on Nov 30th. I know that it was taken way before that, how do I got about finding that out?

Comment: What's the format of the screen shot?  Some image formats include optional metadata, perhaps including the time when the image was created.  Note that this information could be missing or incorrect.  (Or you could just ask your friend.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although unrelated to SO, I think you can not be certain of creatin time of a file, since it can be altered by user, OR when it is being copied to another disk. Look for `Created` and `modified` times since they can be your best guess.

Answer (score 0):

Check the properties of the original file on your friend's computer. Sending the file from his machine to yours typically doesn't preserve properties like creation date.